# res_xmpp.so load error asterisk

Tags: module, asterisk, voip, pbx

I am trying to connect asterisk to Google talk, however I kept on receiving an error saying that the Motif channel is absent. I then realised that res_xmpp.so is not loading. 
all the dependencies are installed and res_xmpp.so as well as chan_motif are selected to be compiled. However, after compiling I get the following error if I try to load res_xmpp.so:

```
[Mar  8 15:08:15] WARNING[2802]: loader.c:824 inspect_module: Module 'res_xmpp.so' was not compiled with the same compile-time options as this version of Asterisk.
[Mar  8 15:08:15] WARNING[2802]: loader.c:825 inspect_module: Module 'res_xmpp.so' will not be initialized as it may cause instability.
[Mar  8 15:08:15] WARNING[2802]: loader.c:915 load_resource: Module 'res_xmpp.so' could not be loaded.
```

Does anyone know ho to solve this problem??????

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to compile one module, without having to recompile the whole source tree, the simplest solution is to add these lines to the source code of the module you wish to compile:

```
/* Changes to nullify checksum brianj */
#undef AST_BUILDOPT_SUM
#define AST_BUILDOPT_SUM ""
```

Digium does something similar when they distribute binary only modules.

Answer (score 0):

You have recompile asterisk and res_xmpp on same system with same compiler.

Asterisk prevent use of module compiled in other environment due to security reasons.

Comment: Thanks arheops. I am not sure I understand though. Doesn't res_xmpp compile when asterisk is compiling? How do I ensure they compile in the same environment?

Comment: Yes. Or install from same source.

Comment: I've recompiled asterisk with res_xmpp and its dependencies from the same source. However, I get the following error: .. **Error loading module 'res_xmpp.so': /usr/lib/asterisk/modules/res_xmpp.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory** .. I am sure the module ws selected to be compiled [*], so I do not kno what the problem is. Any ideas?

Comment: try "ldd /usr/lib/asterisk/modules/res_xmpp.so"

Comment: Thanks arheops...I realise there were build errors during the compilation process that prevented the compilation of some modules.

Comment: Now I get I get the following error where attempting to connect asterisk to GoogleTalk: **No DNS available for XMPP connection when trying to connect client 'google'** Asterisk is configured according to this guide: https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Calling+using+Google

Comment: So you have fix dns. Or better hire skilled admin.